# Laminas-migration doesn't edit Zend files

Tags: zend-framework, migration, laminas

I have a Zend Framework project and I want to migrate it to Laminas.
I have installed the laminas-migration tool. When I run the migrate command I get no errors and everything seem to go as expected.
However the script doesn't edit any of the Zend library files neither the references of Zend's functions inside my controllers.
The only thing that  it does is deleting all files under the vendor directory, modifies my composer files and change only *some* files under the library/Zend/ directory.
Have I misunderstood how this tool is supposed to work?

Comment: Which version of the zend framework did you use? Was ist zend framework 1 oder zend framework 2 or even 3?

Comment: @Marcel I am using the Zend Engine v2.3.0

Comment: Zend Engine is not Zend Framework. So I ask you again. Which version of the Zend Framework do you want to migrate to Laminas?

Comment: @Marcel ah sorry about that... I am using 1.12.20 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct migration from Zend Framework 1 to Laminas is not possible. Zend Framework 1 is way too old for a direct migration to laminas. You have to migrate from version 1 to version 2 first. This is necessary because the differences from version 1 to version 2 are so elementary that there is no backward compatibility from version 2 to version 1.

Here is a Laminas discourse article about the migration from Zend Framework 1 to Laminas: https://discourse.laminas.dev/t/zf-1-11-migration-to-laminas/2002/3

I 'm sorry, but I guess you have to do a lot of refactoring.

Comment: Althought the answer is correct (there is no possible migration from zf1 to laminas), I wouldn't suggest to migrate from zf1 to zf2 and then to laminas. Since a refactoring is required, I'd rather go directly to laminas, avoiding the zf2 step. It is a bit more difficult, but then it won't be necessary to migrate again from zf2 to laminas (which, however, requires inputs from devs)